# How to achieve row number functionality in mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

Table name: **table_one**
Columns : (**id**, **ref_id**, **timestamp**)

```
| **id** | **ref_id** |    **timestamp**       |                              
| 1      | 111        | 2020-04-27 02:59:45    |           
| 2      | 111        | 2020-04-28 02:59:45    |            
| 3      | 111        | 2020-04-26 02:59:45    |
```

I want to implement something like

```
DELETE 
FROM   (
           SELECT *,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY red_id ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) AS rn
           FROM   table_one
       ). 
       s
WHERE  r.rn != 1;
```

Table table_one after execution of above delete query should be like

```
| **id** | **ref_id** |    **timestamp**                                               
| 2      | 111        | 2020-04-28 02:59:45    |
```

I have tried to select the required rows for delete but not getting correct row numbers. Please find my query below:

```
SET @row_number : = 0;   
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT @row_number: = CASE 
                                      WHEN @ci = ref_id THEN @row_number + 1
                                      ELSE 1
                                 END  AS rn,
                  @ci: = ref_id          ref_id,
                  id,
                  TIMESTAMP
           FROM   table_one
           ORDER BY
                  TIMESTAMP              DESC
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
DELETE t1.*
FROM table_one t1, table_one t2
WHERE t1.ref_id = t2.ref_id 
  AND t1.`timestamp` < t2.`timestamp`
```

or the same in JOIN syntax

```sql
DELETE t1.*
FROM table_one t1
JOIN table_one t2 ON t1.ref_id = t2.ref_id 
WHERE t1.`timestamp` < t2.`timestamp`
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=499379d5d8252cdcd5aa8c081d4334d6)

Comment: Please test queries before pasting them here

Comment: @Strawberry What is the problem with these queries? Fiddle added - check. PS. [extended fiddle version](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=24c1028741614521f6dbc9c0d1bacf9a).

Comment: Apologies. I stand corrected - I didn't think you could include `*` in a DELETE!!! Of course, it's meaningless to do so, but that's besides the point.

Comment: @Strawberry *I didn't think you could include * in a DELETE* It is optional and may be easily skipped (`DELETE t1 FROM ...`) - but I'm used to it, the hand writes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`:

```
delete t
    from table_one t join
         (select tt.ref_id, max(tt.timestamp) as max_ts
          from table_one tt
          group by tt.ref_id
         ) tt
         on tt.ref_id = t.ref_id
    where t.timestamp < tt.max_ts;
```

Window functions are not needed for this.